# Web Java - map URL to another URL

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I would like to map `my-domain.com/page` to `my-domain.com/Page.html`so all the hyperlinks and displayed is `my-domain.com/page`.

Can I achieve this in `web.xml` or can this be done only in `javax.servlet.Filter`?
How the `web.xml`configuration or filter code should look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the URL `http://my-domain.com/Page.html` mapped to a servlet you can use servlet mapping. But if you need to map other resources like jsp,html and etc you need url rewriting. A `javax.servlet.Filter` can be used and check the in comming request URL and re direct or forward to the URL which you want or check [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) which is rule based URL rewriter.